# Could not find crash in Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios9

[Sample Iphone App Crash Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AjkJ.jpg)

Hi this is Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports image. I could not found where is crash so can u help me find crash

Answer (score 0):

Use [Symbolicatecrash](https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/) tool, you can check the link to know how to use the tool to symbolicate your crash report.

As far as your crash is concern, it happened in thread 0 however to know exactly what went wrong in code, you need to symbolicate your crash because crash log is only showing addresses.